Pulp Constraint Problem with [i,j] integers not giving the best Solution
What I overall want to do is distribute some values evenly among $H$ groups (using $H = 26$ for example). I want to minimize hours they are calculated by the sum of the value in the group divided by a corresponding value of the quantity of orders in that group.
My biggest issue is that it makes small orders alone instead of putting larger ones. I was having issues too with it listening to the constraint that each row shouldn't exceed $W$ once it was calculated.

# Number of rows and orders
n_orders = K  # Number of orders as integer
m_rows = H  # Number of rows as integer
cases = list(map(float, T.split(',')))  # Convert each case count to a float


# Define the model
model = pulp.LpProblem("Minimize_Total_Hours", pulp.LpMinimize)

# Decision variables: binary variables for assigning each order to a row
x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("x", [(i, j) for i in range(n_orders) for j in range(m_rows)], 0, 1, pulp.LpBinary)

# Additional variable: number of orders assigned to each row
y = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("y", [j for j in range(m_rows)], 0, n_orders, pulp.LpInteger)

# CPH based on the number of orders in a row
def get_cph(num_orders):
    if num_orders == 1:
        return 152
    elif num_orders == 2:
        return 139
    elif num_orders == 3:
        return 128
    elif num_orders == 4:
        return 119
    elif num_orders == 5:
        return 112
    elif num_orders == 6:
        return 107
    else:
        return 104

# Objective function: Minimize total hours across all rows
model += pulp.lpSum(
    (pulp.lpSum(cases[i] * x[i, j] for i in range(n_orders)) / get_cph(y[j])) for j in range(m_rows)
)

# Constraints
# Each order must be assigned to exactly one row
for i in range(n_orders):
    model += pulp.lpSum(x[i, j] for j in range(m_rows)) == 1


# Add constraint that each row must be assigned at least one order
for j in range(m_rows):
    model += y[j] >= 1

# Calculate the number of orders assigned to each row
for j in range(m_rows):
    model += y[j] == pulp.lpSum(x[i, j] for i in range(n_orders))

# Add constraint that total hours per row (SPUR) must not exceed W
for j in range(m_rows):
    cph = get_cph(y[j])  # Get the CPH for the current row
    if cph > 0:  # Ensure we don't divide by zero
        model += (pulp.lpSum(cases[i] * x[i, j] for i in range(n_orders)) / get_cph(pulp.value(y[j]))) <= W , f"Max_hours_per_row_{j}"
    else:
        print(f"Warning: CPH for row {j} is zero, constraint cannot be applied.")



# Solve the model
model.solve()

# Output results
total_hours = 0  # Initialize total hours variable
U = ""  # Variable to hold the string summarizing total hours per row

for j in range(m_rows):
    print(f"Row {j + 1}:")
    
    # Initialize total cases for the current row
    total_cases_in_row = 0
    
    for i in range(n_orders):
        if pulp.value(x[i, j]) == 1:
            print(f"  Order {i + 1} with {cases[i]} cases")
            total_cases_in_row += cases[i]  # Add cases to total for this row

    # Print total cases and total orders for the row
    print(f"  Total orders in row: {pulp.value(y[j])}")
    print(f"  Total cases in row: {total_cases_in_row}")
    
    # Calculate and print total hours for the row
    row_hours = pulp.value(pulp.lpSum(cases[i] * x[i, j] for i in range(n_orders))) / get_cph(pulp.value(y[j]))
    total_hours += row_hours  # Add row hours to total hours
    print(f"  Total hours for row: {row_hours}\n")
    
    # Update U with the total hours for the current row, formatted without spaces
    U += f"{row_hours:.2f},"  # Append total hours with a comma

# Remove the trailing comma
U = U.rstrip(',')

# Print total hours minimized
print(f"Total hours minimized: {total_hours}")

# Output the string summarizing total hours per row
print("Summary of total hours per row:")
print(U)

Value
# Input handling
K = int(input("Enter the number of Orders: "))  # Convert to integer
T = input("Enter the list of orders separated by commas: ")  # Example: "100, 200, 150, ..."
H = int(input("Enter the number of SPUR (rows): "))  # Convert to integer
W = float(input("Enter the maximum working hours per SPUR: "))  # Convert to float

Example inputs
Enter the list of orders separated by commas: 559,493,479,470,456,455,411,411,405,372,343,343,338,317,282,278,5,263,10,258,18,239,20,239,51,238,103,216,122,196,146,185,148,172,159,4,3,2,1
Enter the number of SPUR (rows): 26
Enter the maximum working hours per SPUR: 8

What I got
Row 1:
  Order 7 with 411.0 cases
  Order 36 with 4.0 cases
  Total orders in row: 2.0
  Total cases in row: 415.0
  Total hours for row: 2.985611510791367

Row 2:
  Order 5 with 456.0 cases
  Order 17 with 5.0 cases
  Total orders in row: 2.0
  Total cases in row: 461.0
  Total hours for row: 3.316546762589928

Row 3:
  Order 18 with 263.0 cases
  Order 28 with 216.0 cases
  Total orders in row: 2.0
  Total cases in row: 479.0
  Total hours for row: 3.446043165467626

Row 4:
  Order 12 with 343.0 cases
  Order 20 with 258.0 cases
  Order 32 with 185.0 cases
  Total orders in row: 3.0
  Total cases in row: 786.0
  Total hours for row: 6.140625

Row 5:
  Order 37 with 3.0 cases
  Total orders in row: 1.0
  Total cases in row: 3.0
  Total hours for row: 0.019736842105263157

Row 6:
  Order 4 with 470.0 cases
  Order 14 with 317.0 cases
  Total orders in row: 2.0
  Total cases in row: 787.0
  Total hours for row: 5.661870503597123

Row 7:
  Order 9 with 405.0 cases
  Order 30 with 196.0 cases
  Total orders in row: 2.0
  Total cases in row: 601.0
  Total hours for row: 4.323741007194244

Row 8:
  Order 10 with 372.0 cases
  Total orders in row: 1.0
  Total cases in row: 372.0
  Total hours for row: 2.4473684210526314

Row 9:
  Order 1 with 559.0 cases
  Order 39 with 1.0 cases
  Total orders in row: 2.0
  Total cases in row: 560.0
  Total hours for row: 4.028776978417266

Row 10:
  Order 19 with 10.0 cases
  Total orders in row: 1.0
  Total cases in row: 10.0
  Total hours for row: 0.06578947368421052

Row 11:
  Order 11 with 343.0 cases
  Total orders in row: 1.0
  Total cases in row: 343.0
  Total hours for row: 2.2565789473684212

Row 12:
  Order 21 with 18.0 cases
  Order 23 with 20.0 cases
  Total orders in row: 2.0
  Total cases in row: 38.0
  Total hours for row: 0.2733812949640288

Row 13:
  Order 6 with 455.0 cases
  Total orders in row: 1.0
  Total cases in row: 455.0
  Total hours for row: 2.9934210526315788

Row 14:
  Order 27 with 103.0 cases
  Order 33 with 148.0 cases
  Total orders in row: 2.0
  Total cases in row: 251.0
  Total hours for row: 1.8057553956834533

Row 15:
  Order 13 with 338.0 cases
  Total orders in row: 1.0
  Total cases in row: 338.0
  Total hours for row: 2.223684210526316

Row 16:
  Order 35 with 159.0 cases
  Total orders in row: 1.0
  Total cases in row: 159.0
  Total hours for row: 1.0460526315789473

Row 17:
  Order 22 with 239.0 cases
  Total orders in row: 1.0
  Total cases in row: 239.0
  Total hours for row: 1.5723684210526316

Row 18:
  Order 38 with 2.0 cases
  Total orders in row: 1.0
  Total cases in row: 2.0
  Total hours for row: 0.013157894736842105

Row 19:
  Order 8 with 411.0 cases
  Order 25 with 51.0 cases
  Total orders in row: 2.0
  Total cases in row: 462.0
  Total hours for row: 3.323741007194245

Row 20:
  Order 26 with 238.0 cases
  Total orders in row: 1.0
  Total cases in row: 238.0
  Total hours for row: 1.5657894736842106

Row 21:
  Order 29 with 122.0 cases
  Total orders in row: 1.0
  Total cases in row: 122.0
  Total hours for row: 0.8026315789473685

Row 22:
  Order 34 with 172.0 cases
  Total orders in row: 1.0
  Total cases in row: 172.0
  Total hours for row: 1.131578947368421

Row 23:
  Order 3 with 479.0 cases
  Total orders in row: 1.0
  Total cases in row: 479.0
  Total hours for row: 3.151315789473684

Row 24:
  Order 2 with 493.0 cases
  Total orders in row: 1.0
  Total cases in row: 493.0
  Total hours for row: 3.2434210526315788

Row 25:
  Order 15 with 282.0 cases
  Order 24 with 239.0 cases
  Order 31 with 146.0 cases
  Total orders in row: 3.0
  Total cases in row: 667.0
  Total hours for row: 5.2109375

Row 26:
  Order 16 with 278.0 cases
  Total orders in row: 1.0
  Total cases in row: 278.0
  Total hours for row: 1.8289473684210527

Total hours minimized: 64.87887223116242
Summary of total hours per row:
2.99,3.32,3.45,6.14,0.02,5.66,4.32,2.45,4.03,0.07,2.26,0.27,2.99,1.81,2.22,1.05,1.57,0.01,3.32,1.57,0.80,1.13,3.15,3.24,5.21,1.83


This is a modeling problem. Please write the equations of your mathematical model, and not the corresponding code (harder to read). It will be much easier to help once the model is clearly displayed.

In the model, you have / get_cph(y[j])). That looks problematic (the denominator is a function of variable y). Note that PuLP is for linear models only.

Got it makes sense. I've been tweaking it but there is a problem Mathematically Posting a link to it Since it is a bit difficult to write it out here
linkitalic

I think the problem may not be (entirely) linear, while PuLP expects it to be. You could take a look at constraint programming; it is more flexible in the sense that it does not require strictly linear constraints.
